# How to merge data sets with the same key column in PowerAutomate

Tags: inner-join, power-automate

I have two data sets coming from two separate API calls.
These both give me a list of events, and a number value.
I want to merge these two sets into one table, in PowerAutomate, but I am having trouble figuring out how -- I've tried a nested Apply to Each function but it's not successful.

Example of my data:

Array 1:
| Event Name | Tickets |
|------------|---------|
| General Admission | 510 |
| Members | 210 |
| Special Programs | 100 |
| Groups | 20 |

Array 2:
| Event Name | Checked In|
|------------|---------|
| General Admission | 210 |
| Members | 110 |
| Special Programs | 100 |

(these data are in JSON format, arrays or strings: `[{ "Event Name": "General Admission", "Purchased Tickets": "510"},{"Event Name": "Members", "Purchased Tickets": "210"}....]` and `[{"Event Name": "General Admission", "Checked In": "210"},.....]`)

And what I want to do is merge them into:
| Event Name | Tickets | Checked In |
|------------|---------|------------|
| General Admission | 510 | 210 |
| Members | 210 | 110 |
| Special Programs | 100 | 100 |
| Groups | 20 | |

(ideally the last cell would be 0 but that's something I can figure out myself). The important thing there is to note that both tables might not have identical rows, I just want to treat it as a null for now if so. I don't have a lot of control over *what* key values I get, those are dependant on the ran reports. However if they *do* match, the keys will be identical.

`union` just plops the second array after the first, and then I get a table with two sets of key values, and blank for column 2 and 3 respectively. I think `inner-join` can help me with this but it doesn't seem to give me an option to select both arrays.

I don't have access to any PowerAutomate premium features

Answer (score 2):

A flow such as this will do it for you.  I have to say, this type of manipulation like you're wanting to do is not always ideal on the LogicApps/PowerAutomate engine.  Either way ...

[image: Flow]

To describe each step ...

###### Base Data

This is simply your JSON that is the base data you want to augment with the new data set.

###### Lookup Data

This is the other data set noting that the last record has no `CheckedIn` property.  Obviously, that's an important part of the flow.

###### Initialized Combined Array

This is empty at this stage, it will combine the data in a joined state.

###### Process Each Base Data Item

This is obvious, we're just looping through the `Base Data` array.

###### Filter Lookup Array on Current Base Data Item

It's a bit easier to visualise this action.

[image: Filter]

To show you the code behind that step ...

```
"inputs": {
    "from": "@body('Lookup_Data')",
    "where": "@equals(item()['EventName'], items('Process_Each_Base_Data_Item')?['EventName'])"
},
```

###### Append to Combined Array

There are a couple of ways to do this but to illustrate it all a bit better, we're simply creating a new object and adding that to the `Combined Array` variable.

This is the code contained within the step ...

```
"inputs": {
    "name": "Combined Array",
    "value": {
        "EventName": "@{items('Process_Each_Base_Data_Item')?['EventName']}",
        "Tickets": "@items('Process_Each_Base_Data_Item')?['Tickets']",
        "CheckedIn": "@if(greater(length(body('Filter_Lookup_Array_on_Current_Base_Data_Item')), 0), body('Filter_Lookup_Array_on_Current_Base_Data_Item')[0]['CheckedIn'], 0)"
    }
}
```

The important expression being the `CheckedIn` property.

It checks to see if the filter result had at least one value, if it does, it gets the first (using index 0 but you could use the `first` function) item (I assume there should only be one) and then gets the `CheckedIn` property from that.

The end result is an array that looks like this ...

```
[
  {
    "EventName": "General Admission",
    "Tickets": 510,
    "CheckedIn": 210
  },
  {
    "EventName": "Members",
    "Tickets": 210,
    "CheckedIn": 110
  },
  {
    "EventName": "Special Programs",
    "Tickets": 100,
    "CheckedIn": 100
  },
  {
    "EventName": "Groups",
    "Tickets": 20,
    "CheckedIn": 0
  }
]
```